# Object created inside foreach loop

Tags: php, object, foreach

I'm creating a new object inside a foreach loop and I don't really know how to call a specific object since they all have the same name.

Here is the class :

```
class Item{
    public static $allItems = array();
    public $slot;
    public $id;

    public function __construct($slot, $id){
        self::$allItems[] = $this;
        $this->slot = $slot;
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

And here is the foreach loop :

```
foreach($item_type as $key => $type){
        $itemID = $_SESSION[$type.'ID'];
        $item = new Item($key, $itemID);
    }
```

Is there a way to name them differently or to call a specific instance?

Comment: Yes you can, There is way in PHP call `complex variables` this way allows you to named variable during run-time for example when you crate variable for every user using `user-id` like this `{'user' . $userid}` and call this variable using `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create an associative array with objects and access them as an array elements:

```
$elementsArray = array();

foreach($item_type as $key => $type){
    $itemID = $_SESSION[$type.'ID'];
    $elementsArray[$key] = new Item($key, $itemID);
}
```

Then you can access any of them by (assuming that `$key` is a number):

```
$elementsArray[0]
```

Comment: So instead of using an array inside the object, I should make an array of object? Then I don't need the following property : public static $allItems = array(); ?

Comment: you don't. And you should not keep instances of ``Item`` inside ``Item`` because every each item of collection will have another collection inside, and so on, and so on, and you will end with endless loop

Comment: unfortunately in php you need to first assign value from array to new variable and then access it. So ``$tempVar = $elementsArray[0]; $propertyVal = $tempVar->id``

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make $item contain an array.

```
$item = array();

foreach($item_type as $key => $type)
{
  $itemID = $_SESSION[$type.'ID'];
  $item[$itemID] = new Item($key, $itemID);
}
```